# How to order rows from newest to oldest MySQL & PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I made a comments section on my website using PHP & MySQL. However all the old comments are at the top and the new comments are at the bottom. How do I flip the order so new comments are on top and old ones are at the bottom?

Here's my `comments.inc.php`:

```
<?php
function setComments($conn) {
  if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (uid, date, message) VALUES ('$uid', '$date', '$message')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
  }
}

function getComments($conn) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div class='comment-box'><p>";
    echo $row['uid']."<br>";
    echo $row['date']."<br>";
    echo '<input type="button" value="More Info" onclick="window.location=\'more_info.php?start=' . urlencode($row['message']) . ' \';" />';
    echo "</p></div>";
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: SELECT * FROM comments   ORDER BY date desc

Comment: just use ORDER BY

Comment: @Kevin Is your `comments ` has auto increment id?

Comment: scaisEdge's Anwser Fixed My Problem. Thank You All So Much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY date DESC`

Comment: Thank You, SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY date DESC worked.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the date and time we can show older once at the top and newer  comments at the bottom:

```
SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY date desc
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY date DESC worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY date DESC
```

For more info you can refer below link. All possibilities are listed.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use ORDER BY date DESC or same with primary key field if it is autoincrement when building your query.